# Laptop shut down in between of a git merge

Tags: git, android-studio, git-merge

I was merging 2 branches in Android Studio, and my PC shut down in the middle.

Now when i open android studio. I can see few files red in color, few in green, and my code is not updated.

What should I do? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you post the output of git status.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not related to programming

Comment: offtopic, anyway you can revert

Answer (score 0):

I will always suggest you to use Sourcetree as a git client. As it gives a clear picture of the current status of branch.

And for now I would request you to revert your commit/merge and set the head to last working build. After that try to merge your branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate your state before the incomplete merge by using `git reflog` and `git reset COMMITHASH` and then just rerun the merge.

This piece of documentation should give you the additional details https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog